# Handling URLs correctly -- production vs development (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

My production environment is in a directory off the main url `www.example.com/sample`. Most of my URLs are resolving fine by using `~`, so `~/default.aspx` resolves to `www.example.com/sample/default.aspx`.

However, none of my javascript of css is loading correctly in production. I have the script src set to, for example, `js/sample.js`, and I have tried `~/js/sample.js` and it does not resolve. I tried `runat="server"` in the `<script>` tag, but I got an error sometimes. I have:

```
<script runat="server" src="~/js/sample.js?<%=   MyCode.VersionInfo.JSTag %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Here I am tagging a version code to the end of the filename to force reload during debugging, however, with `runat=server` it complains about this.

I'm sure this is a common issue, and there is a standard idiom for handling it, but I can't seem to find it. Can someone help me? When and how does the `~` get expanded, and how do people handle this type of thing?

Most likely when the web site goes to full production, it will go in without the subdirectory, so I need to handle this systematically.

Comment: The only solution that I've come up with is to use the `ResolveUrl` construct that others have suggested. I find it very frustrating that this is the case, as it is just plain ugly :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what you are looking for is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= this.ResolveUrl("~/js/sample.js?" + MyCode.VersionInfo.JSTag) %>"></script>
```

more information [here](http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/the_script_tag_runatserver_problem_solution_using_resolveurl.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Just use relative paths for js, css and images i.e. js/sample.js

Comment: -, lool! the key benefit of `~` is, that the asp.net-engine does the relative-computation ... that is definitely not the correct way!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<% =HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath & "/js/sample.js"%>"></script>
```

Additionally, if you would like to discover path issues like this earlier, you can set your web application to run under a virtual directory, under Cassini (the built in webserver).

Right click on the Web Project, choose Properties, choose Web, and then type in your Virtual Path - e.g. /sample/.